# Gummi: Extend with Markdown functionality, or suggest Markdown editor

Tags: editors, markdown

I use [Gummi](http://gummi.midnightcoding.org) for my LaTeX work, and I use online [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)<sup>1)</sup> editors, for quick note taking, making protocols, and making quick handouts, etc.

I'd like to combine both. Is there any way, to extend Gummi (which is pretty much [Gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) and a [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) rendering pane in one GUI) with making it render Markdown?

If this is *not* possible, I need a non-RIA<sup>2)</sup> Markdown editor. The best one I could find so far, is [Qute](http://www.inkcode.net/qute). Unfortunately, it is pretty unstable, and the GUI isn't really suited for prolonged working with it (it's quirky and nice, but for one thing, I cannot chose fonts, and it doesn't really do syntax highlighting - for instance the way Gummi does it).

Gummi is a comparably minimalist LaTeX editor, my favorite RIA Markdown editor - [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io/) - implements pretty much everything I need or expect from a nice Markdown editor, as well as having the right *feel* for an editor for that task.

I tried looking into extending Gummi myself, but it seems there isn't really a way to add render plugins, etc. to make it a good Markdown editor. The only other thing I could come up with, is basically implementing a new editor in the likes of Gummi, but with Markdown rendering instead of a Poppler pane for PDF viewing. Unfortunately, I have a day job, and can't really shell out the extra time for that...

---

- <sup>1)</sup> like [dillinger.io](http://dillinger.io/), [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io/), etc.
- <sup>2)</sup> RIA: Rich Internet Applications. Basically a browser window, and the whole GUI and pretty much everything is implemented as a webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no method which would enable Gummi to work with Markdown so you're only options are to use locally installed Markdown editors or switch to another LaTeX editor that perhaps does.

#### #1 - MdCharm

[MdCharm](http://www.mdcharm.com/) looks like a decent option if you just want a basic editor that can handle Markdown locally on your system.

[image: mdcharm]

#### #2 - UberWriter

Another option, [UberWriter](http://uberwriter.wolfvollprecht.de/). This one's unique in that it tries to blend the preview and the editor into a single pane, whereas most other approaches go with the split pane model (one being the editor, the other being a preview).

[image: ss #2]

Comment: I use gedit to edit markdown all the time. Install pandoc, write a Makefile and just press `Ctrl+F8` to compile.

Comment: Qute and UberWriter seem to have a similar approach. MdCharm seems to be the better option. I was unaware, that it is actually open source, I glanced over the website, found a "buy" button, and this made me look elsewhere...

Comment: @polemon - those buy buttons always make me look twice, but it's both, which is fine, software devs have to eat too 8-).